# Как я могу запустить lint для только что измененных и новых файлов?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Я хочу использовать линт, но не могу найти способ запуска только для тех файлов, которые были изменены или добавлены. Причем желательно, что бы это было отдельной таской в gradle которую может запустить каждый разработчик. Я не хочу проверять весь проект и не хочу настраивать каждый раз руками файлы и модули которые я хочу проверить.
причем меня интересует именно встроенный линт, а не другие анализаторы

Comment: `gradle lint` или `gradlew lint` - разве это не то?

Comment: @BarmaleyRedStar так а как мне указать линту, что не нужно проверять все файлы в проекте, а только то, что я изменил или добавил?

Comment: это уже задача `gradle`

Comment: То есть вам делать больше ничего не надо. Gradle сам позаботиться о включении, запуске только для модифицированных файлов